# how to create custom popup using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create simple custom popup using jquery. My html code is as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        alert("Thiws should be custom popup");
    });
   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
  On clicking button it should open a form in popup asking username, email address and also it should have submit button
```

For reference what i want to ask
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/custom-popup-window-using-jquery/

Comment: Why you don't want to use colobox plugin for this?

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery UI Dialog widget.

Comment: If you need help with your code, you need to post the Javascript. We're not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function and css I wrote here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mm7b7t5t/

Opening a hello world popup:

```
var hello = new popup([{text:"Close"}], "Hello!", "<p>Hello World</p>");
hello.open();
```

You can make popups draggable, add multiple buttons etc etc

jQuery dialog is a mess in my opinion, I prefer my own popup code ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just create a html file and copy/paste that code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, height: 400, width: 400 });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```